# redhawk module service function usage example crashes

Tags: c++, redhawksdr

So I am building a redhawk module and trying to just pass data through it as a test.  After putting their example of how to work with input and output ports into the serviceFunction() I am able to build the module with no errors (I changed variable names to match my ports).  When I put the module on the white board and link it up it's fine but as soon as I start the module it crashes.  I added a line to write the incoming stream id to the console and that will hit the console 10 to 20 times before the crash (it correctly writes the id of the signal generator that is providing the signal).  If I plot the output port nothing is plotted before the crash (when I say crash I mean that the module just disappears from the white board, the ide is still up and running).

The service function is:

```
int freqModFrTest_i::serviceFunction()
{

    bulkio::InFloatPort::dataTransfer *tmp = dataFloatIn->getPacket(bulkio::Const::BLOCKING);
    if (not tmp) { // No data is available
        return NOOP;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<tmp->streamID<<std::endl;
        std::vector<float> outputData;
        outputData.resize(tmp->dataBuffer.size());
        for (unsigned int i=0; i<tmp->dataBuffer.size(); i++) {
            outputData[i] = (float)tmp->dataBuffer[i];
        }

        // NOTE: You must make at least one valid pushSRI call
        if (tmp->sriChanged) {
            ComplexOut->pushSRI(tmp->SRI);
        }
        ComplexOut->pushPacket(outputData, tmp->T, tmp->EOS, tmp->streamID);

        delete tmp; // IMPORTANT: MUST RELEASE THE RECEIVED DATA BLOCK
        return NORMAL;
    }
}
```

Has anyone had a similar issue or any ideas on what would be causing this?

Additional Info:

Following the sugestion by pwolfram I built a sig generator and this component into a waveform.  When launching it from a domain I got the error:

```
2016-01-14 07:41:50,430 ERROR DCE:aa1a189e-0b5b-4968-9150-5fc3d501dadc{1}:1030 - 
Child process 3772 terminated with signal 11
```

when trying to restart the component (as it just stoped rather then disapering) I get the following error:

```
Error while executing callable. Caused by org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT:
Retries exceeded, couldn't reconnect to 10.62.7.21:56857
Retries exceeded, couldn't reconnect to 10.62.7.21:56857
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the same setup but using a Waveform instead of the Chalkboard?

Comment: Also, which version of REDHAWK are you using?

Comment: No I haven't tried using a waveform but I'll see if that makes a difference (if it does though it's not a good solution because it will add a lot of time to module development), at the moment we're just trying to get all of the modules we'll need built. The version of REDHAWK is 1.10 on cent os 6.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In REDHAWK 2.0.0 I created a component with the same name (freqModFrTest) and port names (dataFloatIn and ComplexOut) and used your service function verbatim. I did not however get any issues.

Here are a few things to try:

- Clean and rebuild the component. The Sandbox (what you referred to as the whiteboard) will run the binary that has been built. It is possible that you've modified the code and have an older version of the binary on disk. Right click on the project and select "clean project". Then right click and select "Build Project" this will make sure that the binary matches your source code.
- Run the component in debug mode. If you double click on the SPD file, under the "overview" tab there is "Debug a component in the sandbox". This will launch the component in the chalkboard within a debugging context. You can set breakpoints and walk through the code line by line. If you set no breakpoints though the IDE will stop execution when a fatal error occurs. If there is an issue (like invalid memory access) the IDE will prompt you to enter debug mode and it should point out the line in code where the issue is.
- If those options fail, you can enable core dumps and use GDB to see where in the code the issue is occurring. There are lots of tutorials online for GDB but the gist is that before launching the IDE, you'll want to type "ulimit -c unlimited" then from the same terminal, launch the IDE. Now when your component dies, it will produce a core file.

Hopefully one of these gets you going down the right path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested fixes, I just ran the example on another computer running the same setup on a VM and it worked with no issues as well.  Due to all the issues were having we have decided to reformat and do a clean install.